# Simple view function in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I've made a simple blog with a MVC pattern in php based on some net.tutplus.com tutorials. I'm pretty nooby at php though so please help me understand how this works.

I've broken it down to a couple of simple files here. 3 files, index.php, index.view.php and function.php What I wanna know is why do I have to pass my $data array as a second paramater in the view function to be able to access it on my index.view.php? If I drop the $data as second parameter in my view function I get undefined variable and can't access $data on my index.view.php page.

**Index.php**

```
<?php

require('function.php');    
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');    
view('index', $data);
```

**index.view.php**

```
<?php
    foreach($data as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
?>
```

**function.php**

```
function view($path, $data) {
    include($path . '.view.php');
}
```

I'm a bit confused here since whenever I drop the $data variable as second parameter from my view function and within my index file replace **view('index', $data);** with **include('view.index.php');** the $data variable is being passed from the index.php to the index.view.php like expected.

But when I put the view function back without the $data parameter,I get undefined variable data. I thought my view function did exactly the same as **include('view.index.php');**?

Hopefully this makes sense and somebody can explain to a noob what is going on, otherwise ill try to rephrase this a bit.

Comment: It's because the second parameter is not optionnal. Append a default value to allow the call without second parameter: `function view($path, $data = array()) {`

Comment: I can just set the data to null view($path, $data = null). But I'm trying to figure out why I have to pass the $data var as a second param to my view function. Because if I just use a simple include to include my index.view.php I can access the $data var but when I use view('index); I'm unable to use my $data var on the view page.

Comment: Its because you are inside a function, so you are limited to the context/scope of the function. If you want to use a var which is defined outside the function (in the global scope) you have to use the `global` work at the begin of the function. Take a look at the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the include as copying and pasting the body of code where the include is called.

If you copy and paste the body of code where all the includes and requires are, you get this:

```
function view($path, $data) {
    foreach($data as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
}  
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');
view('index', $data);
```

That code should work, but if you remove the `$data` parameter from the view() function, you get something different:

```
function view($path) {
    // $data doesn't exist here, not local to the function.
    // The foreach() loop therefore is trying to access $data variable which doesn't exist.
    foreach($data as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');    
view('index');
```

Comment: Oh wow, this made it really clear to me. Thanks for taking the time to help me out here. Really, really appreciate it. Very good answer.

Comment: "Think of the include as copying and pasting the body of code where the include is called." This doesn't generally hold, mind you. (A fine simplification for this situation nonetheless)

Answer (score 2):

> I thought my view function did exactly the same as
>   include('view.index.php');?

As you have demonstrated, it does not.

```
<?php
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');    
include('view.index.php');
```

In this example, the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) that `view.index.php` sees is `{$data}`.

```
<?php
$foo = "hello world"; // note this extra variable
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');    
view('index', $data);
function view($path, $data) {
    include($path . '.view.php');
}
```

In this example, the variable scope that `view.index.php` sees is `{$path, $data}`. This is because the `include` is happening within the scope of the function.

```
<?php
$data = array('item0', 'item1', 'item3');    
view('index');
function view($path) {
    include($path . '.view.php');
}
```

Therefore, in this example, the variable scope for `view.index.php` is `{$path}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a default value to allow the call like `view('index');`

```
function view($path, $data = array()) {
    // Do some stuff
    include($path . '.view.php');
}
```

If you want to make your global var visible inside your function, use `global`

```
function view($path) {
    global $data;
    include($path . '.view.php');
}
```